# Valgrind closes and prints "Segmentation fault" with no indication of where issue lies

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I run my project in GDB without issues. When I run it in Valgrind, however, it consistently closes and prints "Segmentation fault" to the screen at a certain point without any indication of what the error was. I've tried re-installing Valgrind, updating it to the latest version, and also running gcc with -g flag so far, to no avail. It crashes when I call a certain function in my code, that much I know, so I don't think it's an issue with Valgrind itself. The code being called is too large to paste in here.

-Is there a way to have Valgrind not just close without info, or perhaps have it drop a core dump that I can examine?

-Could the issue be that there isn't enough memory available so it crashes?

```
==7399== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7399== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7399== Using Valgrind-3.21.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7399== Command: ./rom 1235
==7399==
Thu Jun 29 13:55:10 2023 :: Set IP address to 0.0.0.0
==7399== Warning: ignored attempt to set SIGSTOP handler in sigaction();
==7399==          the SIGSTOP signal is uncatchable
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Looks like Valgrind crashed with Segmentation fault. Also you can't run GDB with `-g` flag, you probably did it with GCC.

Comment: Corrected that, yes, I compiled with gcc. Valgrind usually tells you something, not just crashes without any information as to what the error is in your code.

Comment: There are probably no errors in your code. Valgrind itself may have bugs and it can also crash with Segmentation fault. Try to update Valgrind to a latest version.

Comment: It's not Valgrind AFAIK. I upgraded to the latest version and it does the same thing when I call a certain function from my code. Just closes and prints "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Try using Valgrind with `--vgdb-error=0` and then use gdb in a second window and copy and paste the instructions from the first window. The continue in gdb and see where the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: I've done that as well, but it just says remote connection closes when the segmentation fault happens. I rebooted my server and now for some reason Valgrind works fine.

Comment: "t's not Valgrind AFAIK" -- yes, it _is_. You can report this to Valgrind bug tracker if you can make a reproducible test.

Comment: Ever since I restarted the computer, it no longer crashes. I don’t know why. Thanks everyone for the help.